# Idiomatic way to have a copy method in an interface

Tags: go

What is the idiomatic way to have a Copy() method in an interface in Go?

I have a struct `S` that can return a copy of itself.

I also want an interface that can be implemented by anything that can return a copy of itself.

The code below won't compile because you `cannot use S literal (type S) as type I in assignment`, but this is basically what I'm trying to do.

I also don't want to change `(S) Copy() S` to `(S) Copy() I` because: "The implementing package should return concrete types"
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#interfaces

I understand I probably need generics or something, but short of that, how are we supposed to handle this kind of situation?

```
package main

type S struct {

}

func (S) Copy() S {
    return S{}
}

//====== another package ======

type I interface {
    Copy() I
}

func main() {
    var i I = S{}
    i.Copy()
}
```

Comment: you dont want to copy anything in any case. It might contain instance of struct that you can not copy, thinking mutexes.

Comment: @mh-cbon In this case I'm assuming the struct is safe to copy.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this without generics is to define the Copy method to return the interface:

```
func (S) Copy() I {...}
```

You have to return interfaces when you need to.